# Maximum number of expressions in PostgreSQL SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql

What is the maximum number of returned expressions allowed in a PostgreSQL `SELECT` statement?

(Not to be confused with the maximum number of columns in a table.)

Comment: I _think_ the same limit as for tables applies

Comment: I think it is the same number. The result-tuple must have an entry in the range table. BTW: you could check the source.

Answer (score 2):

I found it programmatically: **1664** (version 13).

The limit is a bit higher that the column limit of 1600. This is the error that I get when crossing the limit:

```
ERROR:  target lists can have at most 1664 entries
```

The limit is defined in "src/include/access/htup_details.h" (`MaxTupleAttributeNumber 1664`) next to the column-amount limit  (`MaxHeapAttributeNumber 1600`). The reason for the difference between the two limits is unclear to me.